# Large delay between Artifactory started and deployment finished on Tomcat

Tags: artifactory

We currently have Artifactory running on a Digital Ocean Droplet under Tomcat

Artifactory starts nice and quickly, but the deployment doesn't actually complete until it's done, I can't work out how to get any further information out from either the Artifactory Deployment or the Tomcat Server

```
2017-01-11 13:18:20,707 [art-init] [INFO ] 

(o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:219) -
###########################################################
### Artifactory successfully started (14.442 seconds)   ###
###########################################################
```

From the catalina.log

```
11-Jan-2017 13:18:00.921 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml
11-Jan-2017 13:35:28.086 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml has finished in 1,047,164 ms
```

I'm confused as to what's going on between 13:18:20 and 13:25:28, Artifactory doesn't have a forum anymore and directs everyone here.